# Does bash have different weak quoting rules for special variables?

Tags: bash, shell-script, quoting

I don't think I fully understand the nuances of quoting in bash.

I have a script, `foo.sh`, which simply outputs numbered arguments.

```
#!/bin/bash

i=1
while [ $i -le $# ] ; do
    v=$(eval "echo \$$i")
    echo "$i: $v"
    i=$((i + 1))
done
```

You can use it like so:

```
me@localhost] ./foo.sh a b c
1: a
2: b
3: c
```

If I set the variable `args` to a value containing a space (like `"super nintendo"`), I can use **no-quoting** to have bash treat it as two arguments:

```
me@localhost] args="super nintendo" ; ./foo.sh $args
1: super
2: nintendo
```

Or I can use **weak-quoting** (double quotes) to have bash treat it as a single argument, but expanding the variable to the actual value:

```
me@localhost] args="super nintendo" ; ./foo.sh "$args"
1: super nintendo
```

Or I can use **strong-quoting** (single quotes) to treat it literally as typed:

```
me@localhost] args="super nintendo" ; ./foo.sh '$args'
1: $args
```

However, weak quoting the special variable `$@` seems to act as if there were no quoting. For example, `bar.sh` below calls `foo.sh` twice, once with weak quoting and once with no quoting.

```
#!/bin/bash

./foo.sh "$@"
./foo.sh $@
```

Calling this with `./bar.sh a b c` produces identical output for both calls to `foo.sh`:

```
1: a
2: b
3: c
1: a
2: b
3: c
```

What I **expected** to see was the following:

```
1: a b c
1: a
2: b
3: c
```

What am I missing with quoting in bash here?

Comment: Note that you can avoid the eval by using `${!i}`.

Comment: Another way to write the script: `i=1; for x; do echo "$((i++)): $x"; done`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That's because `$@` is an array, and quoting of arrays has different rules:

- `"${array[@]}"` or `"$@"` expands to members of the array
- `"${array[*]}"` or `"$*"` expands to elements of the array joined by the first character from the `$IFS` variable.

Try it with several arguments, some of them containing spaces:

```
./foo.sh 'one two' three
```

Comment: Winner! Fast reply too.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Special-Parameters.html or the equivalent `man` or `info` on your system